# ModelState in MVC does not show the error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, modelstate

in my controller i have Create action for view .i want to show validation exception with ModelState .but it does not work truly.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: /AgentPosition/Create
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ActionResult Create(Models.AgentPosition.AgentPositionModel model)
    {
        if (model.PositionContacts == null || model.BankAccountDetails == null)
        {
            if (model.PositionContacts == null)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("PositionContacts",Resources.Resource.MustInputPositionContact);
            }

            if (model.BankAccountDetails == null)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("BankAccounts", Resources.Resource.MustInputBankAccountDetail);
            }

            return this.View(model);
        }

        return base.Create(model);
    }
```

in My View

```
 @using (this.Html.BeginForm("Create", "AgentPosition", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    this.Html.ValidationSummary(true);
     <div>
            @this.Html.Partial("BankAccounts", this.Model)
            @this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccountDetails)
        </div>

        <div>
            @this.Html.Partial("PositionContacts", this.Model)
            @this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PositionContacts)
        </div>
```

}

I give only one Exception Validation from ModelState(First Model Error) in View.

I find the answer. 
I must change this code :

```
this.ModelState.AddModelError("BankAccounts", Resources.Resource.MustInputBankAccountDetail);
```

TO

```
this.ModelState.AddModelError("BankAccountDetails", Resources.Resource.MustInputBankAccountDetail)
```

because in MVC we must have same PropertyName in Model and it in dictionary that save exception in modelstate.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to pass false instead of true to your ValidationSummary call. This parameter is excludePropertyErrors, which means if it is set to true, the summary won't show errors relative to PositionContacts and BankAccounts properties.

Comment: Are you sure your Resources.Resource.MustInputPositionContact are well retrieved ? You may also add ModelState into your view, breakpoint near it in your view and check whether it contains any modelerrors.

Comment: My View is :  <div>
                @this.Html.Partial("BankAccounts", this.Model)
                @this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccountDetails)
            </div>

            <div>
                @this.Html.Partial("PositionContacts", this.Model)
                @this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PositionContacts)
            </div>

Comment: Do you see anything from the source code of your rendered view ? Does your view make an asp.net error or just does not show your errors ? Have you tried to not override your controller action ? In your case, I'd probably start over with the simplest ModelError case : no resources, no inherited controller, no null tests, etc.

Comment: Guy.I find the answer plz read the comment that i commented on my post.thank you for response.

Answer (score -1):

Please check that have you included Jquery model validation file in your view like this:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: I must handle server side validation exception in my controller.otherwise i have these scripts in my view.

Comment: In model validation u need to include `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Comment: yes dude.i added these scripts in all of the views.this problem has not any relation with these scripts.